# React .getBoundingClientRect doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, html5-canvas

I am trying to use `.getBoundingClientRect()` to get the position of the current canvas in React. However it keeps returning `DOMRect {x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0, top: 0, …}` but my canvas is not in the top left corner of the page. Any ideas?

Generally I am just trying to get the point that user clicks on the canvas, while the event only returns the absolute position relative to the whole page, so I need the position of canvas (it's dynamic) to subtract that offset. Is there any way that I can get around without doing `.getBoundingClientRect()`?

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.canvasRef = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const c = this.canvasRef.current;
    console.log(c);
    setInterval(console.log(c.getBoundingClientRect()), 1);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div
          className=""
          style={{
            width: "288px",
            height: "188px",
            position: "relative"
          }}
        >
          <canvas
            ref={this.canvasRef}
            style={{
              position: "absolute",
              width: "263px",
              height: "168px",
              top: "10px",
              left: "10px",
              backgroundColor: "#DCDEE0"
            }}
            onClick={e => {
              e.persist();
              console.log(e);
            }}
          ></canvas>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: In the process of trying to reproduce your issue, I put your code verbatim into a runnable snippet (see edit). It seems to work fine here on Stack Overflow, so can you show a [mcve] that illustrates the problem? Also, it's not recommended to use CSS to set canvas height/width. Use the properties of the canvas object, else you will wind up with warping. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you ggorlen I figured it out: the minimal example is that outside of this Example there is a wrapper component that does collapse / expand to show or hide this component. and it returns the collapsed coordinate which is nothing

Answer (score 0):

```
class Canvas extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.canvasRef = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const c = this.canvasRef.current;
    console.log(c);
   setInterval(console.log(c.getBoundingClientRect()), 1);
  }

  onClick = e => {
    const { pageX, pageY } = e;

    console.log(pageX, pageY);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div
          className=""
          style={{
            width: "288px",
            height: "188px",
            position: "relative"
          }}
        >
          <canvas
            ref={this.canvasRef}
            style={{
              position: "absolute",
              width: "263px",
              height: "168px",
              top: "10px",
              left: "10px",
              backgroundColor: "#DCDEE0"
            }}
            onClick={this.onClick}
          />
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```